# MVC 5 Razor special characters not showing up in view

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

My razor view is not rendering the special characters returned from the database.

There are records like...

```
STD-1409
STD-2206
etc...
```

In my view, I am using `@Html.DisplayFor()`

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SupPartNo)
```

It shows the records but without the special character "`-`"

```
STD1409
STD2206
etc...
```

When I add `.ToString()` to the `@Html.DisplayFor()`

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SupPartNo).ToString()
```

It renders this which tells me that the characters are actually making it to the view, but not being rendered properly.

```
STD&#173;1409
STD&#173;2206
etc...
```

I don't ever remember seeing this or dealing with it. What is going on?

Comment: `&#173;` is the soft hyphen and will display when there is a line break between words.

Comment: Interesting... Thanks for pointing that out. I didn't realize there were 2 different special characters for "-".